# python subtract time and run if loop

Tags: python, linux, debian

I want to compare two times and if the new time is more than 2min then the if statement will print output, I can get the output of datetime.datetime.now() , but how do I check whether the old time is less than 2mins?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import datetime
from time import sleep
now = datetime.datetime.now()

sleep(2)

late = datetime.datetime.now()
constant = 2
diff = late-now
if diff <= constant:
    print "True time is less than 2min"
else:
    print "Time exceeds 2 mins"
```

any ideas?

UPDATED:

I am now storing the old date as string in file and then subtract it from current time, the old date is stored in the format

2011-12-16 16:14:50.800856

so when I do

```
now = "2011-12-16 16:14:50.838638"

sleep(2)

nnow = datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

late = datetime.now()

diff = late-nnow
```

it gives me this error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .838638
```

Comment: diff is datetime.timedelta objects and it has .totalseconds() method or .seconds property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtracting two `datetime` instances returns a `timedelta` that has a `total_seconds` method:

```
contant = 2 * 60
diff = late-now
if diff.total_seconds() <= constant:
```

Comment: No worries @krisdigitx...I just happen to have been using this a lot at work lately :)

Answer (score 2):

This is only an answer to the update since the answer from sje397 was perfect.

Use a format string like this to match the whole time string:

```
nnow = datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

The %f matches the microseconds after the dot. This is new since Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare `datetime` objects by themselves:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ts = datetime.strptime("2011-12-16 16:14:50.838638Z", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ')
ts += timedelta(minutes=2) # add 2 minutes

if datetime.utcnow() < ts:
   print("time is less")
else:
   print("time is more or equal")
```